# Installing nVidia drivers from website

Tags: 11.04, unity, drivers, nvidia

My Toshiba laptop has an nVidia graphics card which is not supported in Ubuntu, and there is no Entry in "Additional Drivers"

I tried installing the driver from the nVidia website (Which does have a Linux 64bit version) but nothing happens zwhen I click the .run file (I have made it executable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file should be executed in the terminal, not through the file browser. Please make a backup (preferably using disk-cloning software like [Clonezilla](http://www.clonezilla.org/) before proceeding, better safe than sorry. I have had bad experience with the proprietary drivers because my Optimus card is not supported.

1. Blacklist the nouveau driver by editing the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` as root and add the next lines:

   ```
   blacklist nouveau
   blacklist nvidiafb
   ```

   Alternatively, [open a terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal) and run the next command:

   ```
   printf 'blacklist nouveau\nblacklist nvidiafb\n' | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
   ```
2. Update the modules dependencies map and the initial ramdisk to remove the nouveau drivers by running the next commands in a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal).

   ```
   sudo depmod -a
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```
3. Reboot the machine, and before GRUB is booting, hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to make the menu appear.
4. Select the `(recovery mode)` entry.
5. Choose `root shell`
6. Assuming you've downloaded the file to `/home/user/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-260.19.44.run`, run the program:

   ```
   /home/user/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-260.19.44.run
   ```

   (root permissions is required because the program needs to write drivers and programs to privileged locations)
7. Follow the on-screen instructions

Comment: Thanks! It tells me that I am using an X server so I can't install, even when I am using the terminal by typing ctrl+Alt+1 and not logged in graphically. How do I quit the X server?

Comment: @Calixte: even if you're not using the graphical server, it remains active in the background. **Please make a backup before proceeding!**. To make things easier, I would just reboot into recovery mode. You should have the file ready at some locatio.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The installation failed however. Apparently, the Nouveau has to be disabled first, but there were no instructions on how to do that.

Comment: @Calixte: updated the answer again!

Comment: Everything works perfectly, but then I can't reboot:
* starting load fallback graphics devices [fail]

Thanks for all the help, your instructions are great

Comment: @Calixte: at what step does the error occur? Step 7? You might need to update your modules list and initial ramdisk by running `depmod -a && update-initramfs -u` in a root shell (recovery mode).