# Ubuntu 16.04 NVidia Driver works until reboot

Tags: drivers, nvidia, login, display-resolution

I am currently having problems with my Nvidia driver after upgrading Ubuntu to the latest version. I get 640x480 and a log-in loop.

If I drop to a shell and re-install the driver by executing these commands:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
sudo bash NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.44.run
```

I can do...

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

And everything works again - full resolution, can log in.

After rebooting, I end up with 640x480 and the log in loop again.

I am sure when I originally set up the machine a few years ago, I had to do something else, but I cannot remember what it was.

Any help appreciated.

The card model is a GeForce GTX 750Ti this looks like the same issue as [Login Loop, Video Driver Problem, Reinstalling Driver Fixes until Reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/755700/login-loop-video-driver-problem-reinstalling-driver-fixes-until-reboot?rq=1) which has no answer, so I'll keep this question up to date with my progress...

**Update 1**

Followed [Graphics issues after/while installing Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 with NVIDIA graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics) by doing...

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-370
sudo reboot
```

I got some warnings about uninstalling the old driver during the last command...

```
WARNING: Your driver installation has been altered since it was initially
         installed; this may happen, for example, if you have since installed
         the NVIDIA driver through a mechanism other than nvidia-installer
         (such as your distribution's native package management system).
         nvidia-installer will attempt to uninstall as best it can.  Please see
     the file '/var/log/nvidia-uninstall.log' for details.
```

... and then it outputs some errors like this...

```
ERROR: Unable to create '/usr/lib32/nvidia-370/libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.370.28'
       for copying (No such file or directory)
```

...but it looks like this is due to the uninstall.

Now after a reboot, I do not get the log in loop, but I still only have 640x480 as the only available screen size

I'm going round in circles on this one...

Comment: This is a wrong way of installing Nvidia drivers. Install from Ubuntu repos or a PPA.

Comment: @Pilot6 have tried that (tried quite a lot of things during spare time over the last few weeks), the only way I can get into my desktop at the moment is by doing the above steps every time after a reboot, it's getting annoying... Read hundreds of posts by people with simliar issues...

Comment: The drivers don't actually take effect until you reboot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Graphics issues after installing Ubuntu 16.04 with NVIDIA graphics](http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics)

Comment: @Zacharee1 - think I've tried this before too, but I'll go through it again... I'll close this as a duplicate if so, thanks

Comment: Looks like this user http://askubuntu.com/questions/755700/login-loop-video-driver-problem-reinstalling-driver-fixes-until-reboot?rq=1 has had the same problem... As there are no answers, I am dreading the nuclear option of  "reinstall everything and hope it works" :(

Comment: In my experience (https://superuser.com/a/1613950) nvida GPU's can "remember" things across the reboot boundary.  To be sure you're working with a properly initialized card, either power off and back on, or reboot twice after installing the driver.  I know it sounds crazy--but as it turns out it actually is crazy.

Answer (score 5):

After wasting about 10 hours of my life over this for the past few weeks, I've finally found out what the problem was.

I went back to my original way of installing the driver as in the question.

After powering on my machine, I was in 640x480 mode, so I opened a shell and typed...

```
> lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 vga
```

After a fresh reboot it was listing...

```
bret@bret-Precision-WorkStation-T5500:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 vga
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti] [10de:1380] (rev a2)
        Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti] [10de:1380]
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_352
```

After stopping lightdm, re-installing the driver and starting it again, the command output was...

```
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti] [10de:1380] (rev a2)
        Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti] [10de:1380]
        **Kernel driver in use: nvidia**
```

I then remembered what I did when I originally set up the machine with Ubuntu 14.11, I had to blacklist the other two modules by adding...

```
# Blacklist modules that conflict with NVidia driver...
blacklist nouveau
blacklist nvidiafb
```

to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

Now when I reboot, everything works.

Comment: This jogged my memory... http://askubuntu.com/questions/35273/installing-nvidia-drivers-from-website - I also removed a file that was left by an old nvidia v352 driver in modprobe.d - not sure if this made any difference

Comment: As commented above: *This is a wrong way of installing Nvidia drivers. Install from Ubuntu repos or a PPA*

Comment: I tried this today (2020-05-06) with Ubuntu 20.04, Kernel version 5.4.0-29, a GeForce GTX 1060 6GB/PCIe/SSE2, and the manually downloaded `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-440.82.run`. So far after reboot nothing seems wrong.

---

Note that, to "install the driver", I booted to recovery mode, entered the root shell, navigated to the downloaded driver install file, made the file executable with `chmod +x ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-440.82.run`, and ran it with the command `sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-440.82.run`, and then accepted every prompt that came up.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you update your nvidia driver and the old one is not completely removed. Have faced this and similar ones many times as I had to install/update/reinstall for Deep Learning,CUDA related work.

**Step 1**

If you are able to get a [command line login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop#) via Cntrl +Alt +  F1 ( or F2 depending on your Distro) proceed to Step 2.

Else 
[Edit Grub and get into console mode login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/556406/how-can-i-boot-to-linux-command-line-from-grub) -- This is the simplest and surfire way

**Step 2**

Purge current driver on Nvidia driver

> sudo apt-get purge nvidia*

**Step 3**

> reboot

**Step 4**

Check if GUI is working - should work

Else--
Note if you have tried starting GUI from sudo via startx then there would be permission problems, and you need to [change the permission of.Xauthority](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop#)

**Step 5**

Assuming you are in the GUI or having a network. Install the latest drivers for your card
from https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx. Note sometimes it is better to take a slightly older and more stable version of the driver as the new driver may not work with the old card.

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install nvidia-430
```

like - https://medium.com/techlogs/install-the-right-nvidia-driver-for-cuda-in-ubuntu-2d9ade437dec

**Step 6**

reboot and test using nvidia-smi command
[image]

That's all should solve your problem. If you are having the same problem then try to install a lower more stable version of the driver. For example, I first tried with nvidia-430 and it did not work then tried with nvidia-410 and it was fine.

Answer (score 0):

This question appears in Google Search for a bit different problem: NVIDIA driver stops working after a reboot if the Linux Kernel is upgraded during that reboot.

The solution is the same: https://askubuntu.com/a/1366441/341184