# Ubuntu 16.04 weird booting problem

Tags: boot, 16.04, gnome

I installed Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 on my PC. While booting, after entering my password the monitor switches off. After that I need to press the power button again and it directly takes me to my desktop. It happens in every boot. What can I do?

I tried the `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` command.

It returns

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
Kernel driver in use: i915
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce GTX 750] (rev a2)
Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. GM107 [GeForce GTX 750]
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: i edited my answer with that command.

Comment: I see that Nvidia driver is installed. What is the driver version?

Comment: Its version 367.57 from nvidia-367

Comment: Did you look at this?  http://askubuntu.com/questions/823304/ubuntu-16-04-nvidia-driver-works-until-reboot

Comment: # Blacklist modules
blacklist nouveau
blacklist nvidiafb

Comment: I looked at that.Its not helping